# How to populate succeeding rows with selected specific cell values only?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

So I was trying to make a grading system in vb.net. In my datagridview, I am to create a student's record. I am using MS access database. Since many records will be created for the students, many rows will be created on my datagridview. Now, if I am to put a specific exam item on the first row in a specific cell, how can I get that specific value to the same cell but on the next succeeding rows so that I don't need to manually type in the same exam items for all the records? I'm new to vb.net and I have no idea how to do it. Please help me.

Comment: Question unclear, it is not specific enough.

Comment: See the [DataGridView.RowsAdded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowsadded) event. It's raised when you add a new Row to the DGV. Note that the `e.RowIndex` value is different from the usual, it doesn't *start* from 0 (e.g., if you have 1 Row (Row(0)) and you add a new one, `e.RowIndex` will have value 2, not 1). When the event is raised, copy the value of the preceding Cell of a specifc Column to new Row's Cell in the same Column.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you're talking about, even if it's bogus data.. This question is pretty confusing to us even though it may be clear to you.

Comment: I want to populate specific cells in all the rows of my datagridview with a value that will be inputted on the very first row. Let's say I have 10 columns in one Row, if I input a value of 10 on Row (0)Cell(1), I want all the Cell1 of all succeeding Rows to have the value of 10 without inputting it again. I don't know it I need to create a loop for that or what event I should code it under.

Comment: @Jimi can you please provide me a sample code for that?

Comment: I think my question should be how to programmatically populate all rows with specific cell values from the very first row upon inputting a value in DGV?